# react-native flexbox space-between with two nested views

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

With the following code

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
  <View>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>{hours}</Text>
    <Text style={{alignSelf: "flex-end"}}>h</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>{minutes}</Text>
    <Text style={{alignSelf: "flex-end"}}>m</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>{seconds}</Text>
    <Text style={{alignSelf: "flex-end"}}>s</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{alignSelf: "center"}}>
    <Icon name="cancel" />
  </View>
</View>
```

I get this rendering

[image]

My expectation would be that the first inner view would be treated as a single block put on the left side of the screen and the second inner view on the right. This is not a wrapping issue, the same thing happens if I lower the font size. It looks as if the inner view gets turned into a column. is there a subtle difference from web flexbox that i am missing? Specifically: how do I keep all of the text on a single line while creating space between the `x` icon?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you change the default display settings. display:flex; inorder to use flex properties?

Comment: RN defaults to flex